# Python Tkinter canvas shapes not showing when canvas is gridded, but do when packed?

Tags: python, tkinter

First time on stackexchange
So I've been self teaching myself programming since a month ago, going at it quite slowly.
I've encountered a LOT of problems, since I've been going at it adhoc just rushing through a random tutorial online, not even seen any books or anything, learning by self experience and attempting to build "projects" (which take up so much time to do something simple).

Anyhow, I've ran into many problems and I've solved them eventually, taking up lots of time. Some problems I have bypassed, not knowing what went wrong, but just keeping in mind that something in that area did go wrong.

Well enough of that, I've decided that any problem I can't sort, I can just ask here. So here's a simple one that I can't quite get my head around:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
backgroundCanvas = Canvas(root)
backgroundCanvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N+S+E+W)
#backgroundCanvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

margin= 20
padding = 10
cellWidth = 100
cellHeight = 130

xypos = [ ]
xdif = cellWidth + 2*padding
ydif = cellHeight + 2*padding
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        a = margin+padding+i*xdif
        b = margin+j*ydif
        xypos.append((a,b,a+cellWidth,b+cellHeight))
for xpos1,ypos1,xpos2,ypos2 in xypos:
    backgroundCanvas.create_rectangle((xpos1,ypos1),(xpos2,ypos2), fill = "blue")
    print xpos1,ypos1,xpos2,ypos2

root.mainloop()
```

Sorry for not including a picture, but if I grid it, it only creates 3 full rectangles on the "1st" row, and then 3 other half cut rectangles on the "2nd" row (not the row grid, which is just one block, row 0, column 0). However if I pack it, it displays properly, showing all 16 rectangles.

Thanks in advance for taking your time to read this, I know it's a bit unclear!

Edit: Also another problem (I know I should ask on another post, but it's a smaller problem in scale), say I have four canvases with their parents as root. And their names are as follows:

```
firstCanvas = Canvas(root)
secondCanvas = Canvas(root)
thirdCanvas = Canvas(root)
fourthCanvas = Canvas(root)
```

and say I've packed/gridded them all or whatnot. Now I want to bind my mouseclick to each of them. I do:
firstCanvas.bind("", mousePressed)
fourthCanvas.bind("", mousePressed)

etc..., but what if I had 10 canvases, would I have to paste that line manually for 10 of them? Can I create a loop that binds them all neatly? Problem here is that I cannot do say number+Canvas.bind... etc for number in [first,second,third...], because it just doesn't work like that. Plenty of things undefined not to mention it just doesn't work.

Using strings to go around it doesn't work either because firstCanvas is not a string, it's literally a "variable" pointing to a canvas.

A workaround I have done many times is to create a dictionary, where they DO use strings that can be variables. Eg, for number in [first,...], canvas_data["%d" %(number) +Canvas] = do_your_thing_here, and that works, but it's not very elegant.

Not to mention I'm not even sure using a dictionary variable assigned to an actual Canvas in tkinter actually works (haven't tried). If it does, then I could do that... say 
canvas_data[firstCanvas].bind("", mousePressed).

But that is beside the point, I am looking for another way to do it, anyway to "change" characters that aren't strings?

Another way to put it, I have variables called variableA, variableB, variableC
I want to do something like (2 examples):

```
    for letter in [A,B,C]:
        variable+letter = letter

    varA = 1, varB = 2, varC = 3
    for letter in [A,B,C]: 
        print var+letter.
```

I hope I am clear enough... any help on this matter would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of names `firstCanvas`, `secondCanvas` use list and numbers.

```
canvases = []

for x in range(10):
    canvases.append( Canvas(root) )
```

This way you can create any number of canvases and then you can use it as

```
canvases[0]
canvases[1]
etc.
```

The same way you can then bind to all canvases

```
for c in canvases:
    c.bind(...)
```

or you can do this at once

```
canvases = []

for x in range(10):
    c = Canvas(root)
    c.bind(...)
    canvases.append( c )
```

---

In place of `variableA`, `variableB`, `variableC` use dictionary

```
variables = {}

for letter in 'ABC':
    variables[letter] = letter
```

and

```
variables = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}

for letter in 'ABC': 
    print varaibles[letter]
```

---

As for first/main question - normally grid doesn't change cell size when you resize window.

So cell keeps size (it get size of window) and you see only part of canvas. If you will set window size (or you will set canvas size) you will see more rectangles.

But you can change `grid` behavor to resize row or column when you resize window.

```
backgroundCanvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N+S+E+W)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # resize row 0 vertically
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # resize column 0 horizontally
```

BTW: use `backgroundCanvas.pack()` - without aguments - and you get only part of rectangles too.

---

[Tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm): [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you for the dictionary naming tips, that is very neat. As for the gridding, I actually did forget to weight the columns, but even after I did, it didn't work. I think I weighted the backgroundCanvas instead of the root, your code did the trick!

Comment: In other GUI frameworks you would see something like `root.add_to_grid( backgroundCanvas, column=0, sticky=...)` in place of `backgroundCanvas.grid(...)`  and you would know which widget managed grid and where to use `grid_rowconfigure(...)` :)